# How do I get the two last dimensions of an N-D array as a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix, n-dimensional

I have a 3D array in MATLAB, with `size(myArray) = [100 100 50]`. Now, I'd like to get a specific layer, specified by an index in the *first* dimension, in the form of a 2D matrix. 
I tried `myMatrix = myArray(myIndex,:,:);`, but that gives me a 3D array with `size(myMatrix) = [1 100 50]`.

How do I tell MATLAB that I'm not interested in the first dimension (since there's only one layer), so it can simplify the matrix?

Note: I will need to do this with the second index also, rendering `size(myMatrix) = [100 1 50]` instead of the desired `[100 50]`. A solution should be applicable to both cases, and preferably to the third dimension as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) function, which removes singleton dimensions.

**Example:**

```
A=randn(4,50,100);
B=squeeze(A(1,:,:));
size(B)

ans =

    50   100
```

This is generalized and you needn't worry about which dimension you're indexing along. All singleton dimensions are squeezed out.

Answer (score 2):

```
reshape(myArray(myIndex,:,:),[100,50])
```

Answer (score 0):

`squeeze`, `reshape` and `permute` are probably the three most important functions when dealing with N-D matrices. Just to have an example how to use the third function:

```
A=randn(4,50,100);
B=permute(A(1,:,:),[2,3,1])
```