# How to change dimenssion of a n-d array without using reshape function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an array of kxnxmxt. When i retrieve one element it is like A(i,:,:,:) and the result is 1xnxmxt array. I want it to be only nxmxt and i dont want to use reshape for efficiency reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicates: [How do I get the two last dimensions of an N-D array as a 2D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720062/how-do-i-get-the-two-last-dimensions-of-an-n-d-array-as-a-2d-array), [Matlab: how do I change the way a matrix is stored? from 1x1x3 to 1x3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723563/matlab-how-do-i-change-the-way-a-matrix-is-stored-from-1x1x3-to-1x3)

Comment: hi gnovice
this is a duplicate...
should i remove the question or to do what???
thanks

Comment: It's up to you. You can [flag your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560) and request that a moderator close it or delete it. [Closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) that are duplicates are sometimes left around as sign-posts making the older duplicate questions easier to find, and sometimes they are just [deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) as unnecessary. If you're unsure, just flag it and ask to have it closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
squeeze(A(i,:,:,:))
```

It removes the additional dimension